# Where is the code for dirent.h (opendir, readdir, closedir)? Undefined symbol

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header-files

I'm using Tiny C compiler to compile some C code that uses dirent.h
(Just trying to list a directory's contents)
When I compile, I get these errors:

```
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'opendir'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'readdir'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'closedir'
```

When I open up dirent.h, here's those 3 function headers:

```
DIR* __cdecl opendir (const char*);
struct dirent* __cdecl readdir (DIR*);
int __cdecl closedir (DIR*);
```

This might sound stupid, but where is the actual code for these function headers? It seems to me that's the reason why it doesn't compile.

How can the compiler compile something with just the headers and no the .c code?

Thanks.

Comment: It can link to a library. If it's know the function signature, it knows how many and what arguments to pass, and what to expect back. It looks like a linker problem.

Comment: The compiler does not need code, it only needs to know the names and arguments. The actual *code* is in a separate `.lib` file, and it's the *linker's* responsibility to locate it.

Comment: Under which operating system? What is the compilation command (order of arguments to `tcc` - or to `gcc` if you used it - matters a lot)?

Comment: OK like a DLL file?  Therefore should I have a file called dirent.lib on  my computer??  (I don't..)    I'm using WINDOWS by the way.

Comment: OS: Windows 7. Compilation command: tcc -o cent.exe cent.c

Comment: Where is your dirent.h coming from? It's not part of the standard C language, it's a POSIX extension and as such not typically found on Windows unless you've gone out of your way to find a POSIX implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently readdir, opendir, closedir are UNIX functions and not available on windows.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/94eb8505-01fc-4082-99b8-87231552951d/vc-equivalent-of-dirent

UPDATE: I found some C code ported to windows which works. See link here:

http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/code/dirent/dirent.html

http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/code/dirent/dirent.c

http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/code/dirent/dirent.h

Comment: Just FYI anyone else searching, it is still available on the wayback machine. https://web.archive.org/web/20190717230650/http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/code/dirent/dirent.c

Answer (score 1):

Stop using archaic compilers.

Just use [GCC (MinGW-w64)](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php#mingw-builds) or MSVC. You need the POSIX functionality which just happens to be implemented in MinGW-w64 GCC, so you that.